# formatted file input

Tags: java, parsing

input format thru a file

> 4
>
> (6,7)(8,9)
>
> 5
>
> (8,9)(6,7)

I wrote the following code to get all the integers stored in an array

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{   
   
    int n=0;
    int arr[]= new int[13];
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"));
    s.useDelimiter("[,() ]{1,}");
    
    while(s.hasNextInt())
    {   arr[n]=s.nextInt();
       
        n++;    
    }
    s.nextLine();
    
    while(s.hasNextInt())
    {   
        arr[n]=s.nextInt();
        n++;            
    }
    s.nextLine();
    
    while(s.hasNextInt())
    {   
        arr[n]=s.nextInt();
        n++;
    }
    s.nextLine();

    while(s.hasNextInt())
    {   
        arr[n]=s.nextInt();
        n++;
    }    

    n=0;
    while(n<9)
    { 
        System.out.println(arr[n]);
        n++;
    }
}
```

but it gives only those integers contained within the bracket.

Output

6

7

8

9

8

9

6

7

Desired Output-

4

6

7

8

9

5

8

9

6

7

How can I have 4 and 5 also  in array?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use something like [How do I create a Java string from the contents of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/326390/684934) to get the contents as a string, then use

```
String[] items = fileContent.split(",()[]{}\\s");
```